# Accessing a variable other than a foreign key from a django model?

Tags: django, django-models, autocomplete, django-crispy-forms

I have a class model called "Product" that has the proprieties: ID, number and **type**.
[image]

```
class Product(models.Model):
        PRODUCT_TYPES = (
                ('CW', 'Casement Window'),
                ('BA', 'Bunny Advance'),
                ('EW', 'Enterprise Wadoo'),
                ('T3', 'Type 3')
                )

        number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        type = models.CharField(max_length = 2 , choices=PRODUCT_TYPES)
```

---

I have a class model called "Project" that has the proprieties: ID, number AND a link to "Product" by product_id.

[image]

```
class Project(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

Here is where it gets tricky: I use crispy form & autocomplete to show and edit the values. Autocomplete base it's values on the Project Model. So, in order to show and edit the Product's **type** propriety, i need to add, in my Project Model, a propriety **type**.

[image]

Question:

1. Is it possible to use the models.ForeignKey for a normal field? Such as :

   `type = models.ForeignKey(Product,related_name='type')`
2. I tried using a loop to iterate though every Product and compare the ID, but i got the      following message : "*'ModelBase' object is not iterable*"

   ```
   def test(id_product):
      for p in Product:
          if p.number == id_product:
              return p.type
   ```

**Edit:** I just need to be able to access to Product's TYPE within Project in any way possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to accomplish. However, you cannot loop through an object, but

```
for p in Products.objects.all():
    ....
```

should work well enough. Having type in both `Product` and `Project` when `Project` has a `ForeignKey` to `Product` seems a bit too much.

EDIT:

Still doesn't makes sense, but your test method should yield something like

```
return Products.objects.get(type=id_product)
```

Comment: I added images so that it's clearer. The reason i need the same value in Project is that the crispy form & auto complete needs this code: `widgets = {'customer': autocomplete_light.ChoiceWidget('CustomerAutocomplete'),
            'product': autocomplete_light.ChoiceWidget('ProductAutocomplete'),
                }`
So, i need to have a field for every field i want to auto complete

Answer (score 0):

> Edit: I just need to be able to access to Product's TYPE within
>   Project in any way possible.

I'm also not sure exactly what the issue is, can't you just access it as normal:

```
<my-project-instance>.product.type
```

Accesses the products type within project.

EDIT: Make sure you are using an **instance** of Project. Your comments below are failing as you are using the class name.

Comment: It's very hard for me as this application is half done and written by someone else. I thought that foreign_key was returning the key, not an actual object. Are you suggesting something like this?
`models.Project.product.type`. Because in this case, he doesn't recognize type as a variable of product

Comment: Nope, it points to the object instance, not a key. You need an *instance* of Product, not a class name as your example above shows. That's why your example isn't working. Updated my answer.